# What happens to registered applications when the owner is deleted

Tags: yammer

An application was registered in a particular users account to allow a website to use the login in with Yammer button and to be able to post to Yammer.

If this users account is deleted, what will happen to the application? Will it stop functioning as the client ID and client secret key are revoked?

Can the registered application be migrated to another users account?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/app-registration it is best practise to register applications with a service account as the application will cease to work if the app owner leaves.